# Develop an Order Management System based on the diagram

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAADW.png)

This is what I did so far: https://github.com/akmalhakimi1991/PSLJavaAssignment2/tree/master/question3

This is what I suppose to do:

1. Create StockItem class
2. Create PurchaseOrder class
3. Create OrderItem class

Create Test class that does the following

i. Create 3 customers - Jamie, Bill, Joe
ii. Create 5 items - Milk, Chicken, Egg, Apple and Orange
ii. Create 3 Purchase Orders. 2 for Jamie, 1 for Bill and None for Joe.
a. PO 1 - 2 gallons Milk, 2 lbs Chicken and 12 eggs.
b. PO 2 - 5 apples and 10 oranges
c. PO 3 - 5 Lbs chicken and 10 apples
iv. Get all the orders to be shipped and print labels
v. Ship first order for Jamie
vi. Ship Bill’s order
vii.    Ship Jamie’s order
viii.   Print total sales by customer
ix. Print all invoices (include customer, Order date, line items with count and price, sum for the invoice at the bottom)

I don't know what to do after creating the 3 customer instance. I don't know how to link between all this class/object, ie: creating PurchaseOrder for each Customer. And how would I link the OrderItem with PurchaseItem?

Do I need to use inheritance for this?

Comment: I'm not willing to pull your code from GitHub.  Better to post it here.  How to link?  Think "composition".  What are the relationships between those classes?  I'd guess that a PurchaseOrder would have zero or more OrderItems.  An OrderItem should be 1:1 with StockItem.

Comment: Do I need to use inheritance for this? - No. Just try modeling these objects in your head as if it was real life and then write the program accordingly. Like a PurchaseOrder has OrderItems which should check to see if theyre in stock (StockItems).

Comment: Making a new PurchaseOrder would then probably benefit from another function to create OrderEntry, maybe like

PurchaseOrder.addEntry(StockItem, int); But it's a bit vague for me to write code.

Comment: so how about i add quantity as a variable and see if theyre in stock(StockItems)